# Bayes theorem for dependent events

Tags: probability, bayesian

I am new to Bayes theorem; In Naive Bayes, we assume that events are independent. How does Bayes theorem modify if the events are dependent ?

Answer (score 1):

The theorem stays the same. The term Naive Bayes is short name for Naive Bayes *classifier*. Here, while calculating the posterior probability, we assume conditional independence over the input dimensions:
$$p(\mathbf x |C_k)=\prod p(x_i|C_k)$$

So, we have the class posterior as below:
$$p(C_k|\mathbf x)=\underbrace{\frac{p(\mathbf x|C_k)p(C_k)}{p(\mathbf x)}}_{\text{Bayes Classifier}}=\underbrace{\frac{p(C_k)\prod p(x_i|C_k)}{p(\mathbf x)}}_{\text{Naive Bayes Classifier}}$$

Without the naive assumption, Bayes classifier directly calculates the class conditional probability, $p(\mathbf x| C_k)$. So, the theorem has nothing to do with the *naive* assumption we make. See here for more on [terminology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier#/Probabilistic_model).

Comment: The misconception in OP seems to be that *naive Bayes = Bayes theorem*, I'm not sure if your answer is clear enough on this.

Comment: @Tim tried to elaborate more on the topic